# SOAP Request to the server in ios

Tags: ios, xml, web-services, soap

i am facing a problem while requesting server in SOAP format. when i am pasting the Soap envelope in the the browser(just for testing the web services) then it gives correct response. But when i am requesting from app then it give me irrelevant response.
I searched  a lot on but every where i found the same technique for soap request.
Here is my code what i am using.

```
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<ProfileLogin xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
"<strLoginRequest>"
"<email>abc@gmail.com.au</email>"
"<password>123456</password>"
"</strLoginRequest>"
" </ProfileLogin>"
"</soap:Body>"
"</soap:Envelope>"
];
NSLog(soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com.au/mobileapp.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ProfileLogin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

> and getting response
>
> > <ProfileReply><Success>False</Success><Error>Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</Error></ProfileReply>

please some buddy let me know it is my fault of mycode or from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[theRequest setValue:@"application/soap+xml;charset = utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: @ A Bao  I tried but it give me the response. The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

Comment: @aloksrivastava maybe you count msgLength is wrong. It is lenght of NSData return in [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[theRequest setValue:@"ProfileLogin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```

instead of

```
[theRequest setValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ProfileLogin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```

Comment: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: ProfileLogin.